# Running SQL Query with 1000+ criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to exclude a population of people of about 13,000 participant ID's. SQL will only allow up to 1000 records in the Where or And clause, so i would have to run my query 13 times. I tried the WITH Clause and it didn't exclude them.

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle and Snowflake-- which one are you actually using?  Where are these participant IDs coming from?  If you are using Oracle and the source is another query, an `IN` clause can have a query that returns as many rows as you'd like.

Comment: Store all 13000 ids to exclude in a separate table (maybe a temp one) and perform an anti-join against it.